# Hammer arrestor integrated on valve for faucet, will it prevent hammer from dishwasher?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, dishwasher, water-hammer

Renovating my kitchen. My hot water pipe comes up through the floor upwards. There is a first tee that goes left ending with a valve for the dishwasher. The pipe continues up the tee to the valve for the faucet that has an integrated hammer arrestor. Here's a diagram:
[image: diagram]

I don't think the kitchen faucet needs the hammer arrestor, but I know it's recommended for the dishwasher to have it. Is this setup sound? Or should I rearrange the valves so that the dishwasher's valve is the one with the integrated hammer arrestor?

I have the exact same setup mirrored for the cold water pipe except it serves my fridge's water/ice maker instead of the dishwasher.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally the hammer arrest or should be as close as possible to the item it is protecting - otherwise the pipe between the item and arrest or is subjected to more risk.

However, your diagram suggests that the distance is measured in a few inches.

We had a hydro turbine where the hammer protection was a surge pipe that had to be 45 feet away from the turbine as the turbine was part of a display. So we used a better grade of pipe for that section - never failed but the surge pipe did get used :)

Comment: Correct. The hammer arrestor is less than a foot away from the dishwasher’s valve.